# getting all clockify users with all memberships

Tags: clockify

I inherited someone elses GO code that stopeed working. After brief debugging it seems the culprit is one of last API changes in clockify:

```
Updated default parameter for "Find all users on workspace" from ALL to NONE
```

This is how I try to get data with curl:

```
curl \
--request GET \
-H "Accept: application/json" \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-H "X-API-KEY:myAPIkey" \
-d '{"memberships":"ALL"}' \
--url "https://api.clockify.me/api/v1/workspaces/myworkspaceID/users"  > ./out.txt
```

and here is example (edited) output:

```
[
    {
        "id": "111111111111111",
        "email": "xxx@google.com",
        "name": "Real Name",
        "memberships": [],
        "profilePicture": "https://img.clockify.me/no-user-image.png",
        "activeWorkspace": "11111111111111111111",
        "defaultWorkspace": "11111111111111111111",
        "settings": {
            ...
        },
        "status": "ACTIVE"
    },
    ...
]
```

As you can see, memberships is an empty array, and the GO code looks for this data.
How do I request it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I just need to pass it as URL part

```
curl \
--request GET \
-H "Accept: application/json" \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-H "X-API-KEY:myAPIkey" \
--url "https://api.clockify.me/api/v1/workspaces/myworkspaceID/users?memberships=ALL"  > ./out.txt
```

Comment: does not work for me, unfortunately.